# Many to one self refering to SQLAclhemy table, and returning the table content

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have 2 tables, "tems" and "item_sets". Items in "items" table can exists alone, or one item can be children of 1 or multiple items. "item_sets" is used to map parents of those children's. Models are defined currently as:

```
class Item_sets(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item_sets'

    id_item_old = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True), ForeignKey('items.id'), primary_key=True)
    id_item_new = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True), ForeignKey('items.id'), primary_key=True)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    #with_variant() allows sqlalchemy to auto assign the id's, since bigint is foreign to it
    id = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True).with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    old_items = relationship(Item_sets, secondary='old_items', primaryjoin=id==Item_sets.id_item_new, lazy='joined')
```

With relationship I have mapped items so that it can find all the parents it has. For example when I do this:

```
items = DBSession.query(Item).filter(Item.id == 10).first()
for item in items.old_items:
    print (item.id_item_old, item.id_item_new)

    >>> (1,10)
    >>> (2,10)
    >>> (3,10)
```

But now I have no idea how to change that code, so that print would print parents from the Item table, and not id's from Item_sets table. And I would like to do this using relationships in a Item table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self-referential many-to-many relationship from `Item` to `Item` through `item_sets`, not a many-to-many relationship from `Item` to `Item_sets` through `old_items` (?).

```
old_items = relationship(lambda: Item, secondary=Item_sets.__table__,
                         primaryjoin=id==Item_sets.id_item_new,
                         secondaryjoin=Item_sets.id_item_old == id)
```

Side note: your `id_item_old` and `id_item_new` foreign keys should point to `'items.id'`, not `'item.id'`.